# Very strange behavior with Vim syntax and filetype detection

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, file-type

I have a file, called WrongFileTypeDetection.R, containing the following text:

```
# This file is sometimes wrongly detected as a conf file
```

I also have two versions of _vimrc, that I would have thought to be absolutely identical. However, when I use  the first version, the above file is incorrectly detected as a "conf" file, even though I've specifically asked for all files ending with .R to be set to filetype=r. When I change to the second version (moving "syntax on" behind the augroup definition), detection works correctly again. Note that this is the *only* configuration I have (I moved away my standard vimrc while debugging this).

First version:

```
syntax on
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.r,*.R     setfiletype r
augroup END
```

Second version:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.r,*.R     setfiletype r
augroup END
syntax on
```

It seems that vimrc is very sensitive to the particular ordering of the two files.
Why would this be, considering that one of the lines is an autocommand that will be run much later anyway? Is this a bug in Vim or is this a feature that I'm just not understanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer to your problem is that these lines shouldn't be in your vimrc at all. The officially supported way to handle this is create a `filetype.vim` file in your `.vim` directory containing the following:

```
" my filetype file
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.r setfiletype r
augroup END
```

As for why your code is behaving how it does, it's actually quite a bit more complicated than [@too much php's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291955/very-strange-behavior-with-vim-syntax-and-filetype-detection/1291971#1291971) implies.

In the first version of your `vimrc`, filetype detection is initialised by your `syntax on` line. This works by setting up an autocmd to fire when a file with a `.r` extension is opened, and this autocmd calls the function `s:FTr()` in filetype.vim.

However, your `autocmd!` line overwrites this existing autocmd<sup>1</sup>, so the `s:FTr()` function never runs<sup>2</sup>. Your autocmd then fires, but it *doesn't* set the filetype, because the `setfiletype` command thinks that the filetype has already been set<sup>3</sup>.

Then, because the filetype is still not actually set, Vim attempts to assign one based on the contents of the file, and ends up assigning it to the `conf` type<sup>4</sup>.

The best reference for all this is `:help filetype`. And specifically in your case `:help new-filetype` and `:help remove-filetype`. The `:verbose` command is also very handy for figuring out which settings have been set by what script.

<sub>1: Because of the `!`. If you were to remove this `!`, then you would find the filetype being set correctly. This is not the correct solution, though, because then you will be allowing the file to be set to one type (and applying all the settings for that filetype) and then changing it to another. If the second filetype doesn't overwrite all these settings, some may remain, which might not be what you want.</sub>

<sub>2: Try running `:set autocmd BufRead *.r` when you are using the two different vimrc files. Note the difference in the output given.</sub>

<sub>3: See `:help setfiletype`. Note that if you change the line `setfiletype r` into `set ft=r` in the first version of your vimrc, the filetype *will* be set to r. However, see footnote 1 for why this is not the best solution.</sub>

<sub>4: ...in a line of code which is commented: "check this last, it's just guessing"</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Rich, that is a very detailed and thoughtful answer. I'll keep this in mind and refer to it whenever I have to fiddle around with filetype detection in Vim.

Comment: @Magnus You're welcome. I didn't add it to the answer, because I thought there was already plenty of info in there, but I also did some debugging with `vim -D` to help figure out exactly what was set at what time.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem seems to have cropped up at least in CentOS 7.6.1810 with vim version 7.4.160-5 at the least and I actually do use ~/.vim/filetype.vim and only have options for the types e.g. formatting options in .vimrc. That's how I came across this question. It's quite annoying because any C pre-processor directive in source/header files makes vim detect it as a conf file the next time it's opened. Thus completely changing the colouring options etc.

Comment: @Pryftan Whilst it's the same symptom, it sounds like the root cause is subtly different for you. To debug, you could try first double checking that your autocommand is being fired, and then check what's overriding the filetype by running the command `:verbose set filetype?` in a buffer where the filetype is wrong.

Comment: @Rich Ta. Actually it seemed to resolve itself. I honestly don't know what it was. I have been so exhausted too that I don't know what to trust. Either way it seems fine now. I had thought it odd and so it was. More odd is I didn't change anything at all nor were there any updates. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. Actually though I did check *:set filetype* but not *:verbose ...* All I noticed is that it happened if the file had lines (presumably only starting with but no idea about whitespace) '#'. And only after opening it: if I had added it in a new file it wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 7):

In your first version, **syntax on** is triggering the filetype detection *before* your autocommand has been added.

Answer (score 2):

According to this site

> http://www.build-doctor.com/2008/06/04/how-to-set-the-filetype-in-vim-when-the-extension-doesnt-match/

You just need to add two lines of code in your .vimrc file.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.R set filetype=r
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.r set filetype=r
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will work, but it's not ideal. See footnote 1 to my answer for more details.