# Vim plugins cannot recognize python files in CentOS

Tags: python, linux, vim, centos, vim-plugin

I tried two vim plugin collections called [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) and [dot-vimrc](https://github.com/humiaozuzu/dot-vimrc) in Vim 7.2 on CentOS 6.4 to write my python code. Python mode uses [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to manage plugins and dot-vimrc uses [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

The problem occurs when hash-tag appears on top of my python file, pathogen and vundle won't load my plugins.

[image]

No code highlight for function name and 'import' and no auto completion. And when I installed vim 7.4, the same problem happened.

When the problem occurs, if I type `set ft`, vim recognizes my python file as a 'conf':

[image]

Then I try the command: `set ft=python`, the problem disappears. Python highlighting and auto completion come back.

[image]

I guess the problem occurs when vim opens a file and doesn't recognize it as a python file. So, how can I make vim recognize python files correctly?

Comment: Do you use `filetype plugin indent on`?

Comment: @cyphar Yes, I have set "filetype plugin indent on" in my vimrc.

Comment: What is your vim version?

Comment: @cyphar I use vim 7.2 and I tried vim 7.4, the same problem occurs. And I found that, vim recognize python file to 'conf' when hash-tag appear on the first line. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: What happens when you start the file with `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: The file type vim recognize as 'conf', and the plugins doesn't work. Then I set it to python using 'set ft=python', the plugins works correctly. So How can I make vim recognize python file correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a `python.vim` in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/`?

Comment: @cyphar Yes. I have the python.vim in this directory.

Comment: Why do you even use a shebang? Python doesn't need it and it's most certainly what makes Vim loosing his mind.

Comment: @romainl I also use shebangs in python files, and vim understands it's a python file. I use them so I can `chmod +x` the file and `./file.py` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same problem asked: [Very strange behavior with Vim syntax and filetype detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291955/very-strange-behavior-with-vim-syntax-and-filetype-detection).

I used vim 7.2 on CentOS 6.3, it's fine to open python file with shebang. Maybe it is a bug for vim 7.2 on CentOS 6.4.

As a result, I add one line in .vimrc according to this article [How To Add A File Extension To vim Syntax Highlighting](http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set filetype=python
```

Now vim 7.2 on CentOS 6.4 can recognize my python files with shebang.

Comment: as a sidenote, I also have the `au` grouping for `*.py3` as I've seen that extension used periodically.